# Why is strong duality holds even though the problem is not convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I write the question $5.29$ in Convex Optimization ,and it said

minimize $-3x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_3^2+2(x_1+x_2+x_3)$

subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$

so strong duality holds even though the problem is not convex

I wonder that if we have to prove it is strong duality and not convex,how should we prove it?

Comment: Perhaps you can read page 229 of the book (which is referred to from the question).

Comment: The problem actually becomes convex if we substitute $x_1^2=1-x_2^2-x_3^2$ and $x_1=-\sqrt{1-x_2^2-x_3^2}$ into the objective function subject to $x_2^2+x_3^2\le 1$.